# ClickToDeply Image doe snot have PHPMyAdmin Installed

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Am I just Crazy or in this google click to deploy image does not have PHPMyAdmin installed. It says it does but it does not seem to be installed/ If this is the case and it is not installed who do I tell to make sure it gets fixed?

https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/click-to-deploy-images/lamp

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is installed. What steps did you follow to setup and secure MySQL first and then setup and secure PHPMyAdmin? Edit your question with details on what steps you performed after launching the instance.

Comment: Based from your link for **LAMP Stack Google Click to Deploy**, you should be able to see on the **Overview** tab under *Additional details**, Package contents include **phpMyAdmin 5.0.2**.

Comment: @AlexG I know it says it should be there, I am just not a super Linux GURU and it says it should be there but there is nothing once I spin it up. I don't see any configuration in Apache for it. And after doing an entire system search for the config folder phpmyadmin it came up blank. I was wondering if a real Linux admin could launch this image and verify that I am not crazy. I know it will cost you a few cents to spin one up but I had to manually install it last night.

Comment: @JohnHanley Where is it installed on the machine? I did a 'find / -type d -name "phpmyadmin"' I looked at what packaged were installed and none were. I know you are asking me to update the question but I don't understand how making sure I secured my MySQL & PHPMyAdmin would make a package show up. How can I secure an package that is not installed. Did you spin up the image I linked to?

Comment: @SteveMain I just tried to spin up the same deployment and verified that it has the `PHP 7.4.15 (cli) (built: Feb 12 2021 14:49:58) ( NTS )`. You can use `php -v` to check what php version is installed on the system or you can look at the `/etc/php` path.